# Unexpected output in react

Tags: reactjs

I am fetching data using AJAX request and storing that into `state`. Then I am trying to print it in console . I am getting empty array in below code

```
state = { 
    addressOject: []
};

view = value => {
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/addresses/show/'+ value, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + Auth.getToken(),
        },
        body: JSON.stringify()
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseData) => {
        this.setState({ addressOject: responseData.data[0]});
    })        

    console.log(this.state.addressOject)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Reason**
Since this is an asynchrnous operation, the console.log will be executed as soon as the fetch request is executed but even before its completion.

**Fix**
So you can place the logging statement inside the `.then` so that, the console.log will work after you get the response.

```
 view = value => {
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/addresses/show/'+ value, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + Auth.getToken(),
        },
        body: JSON.stringify()
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseData) => {
        this.setState({ addressOject: responseData.data[0]},()=>{
          console.log(this.state.addressOject)
        });
    })         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because Promise is asynchronous. Before `then` will fire with the response from a server, and the state will get updated with `setState` (which is also asynchronous) your console log has already run.

You can print the updated state in `setState` callback function which will run after state has been updated:

```
this.setState(
  { addressOject: responseData.data[0]},
  () => console.log(this.state.addressOject)
);
```

Also, you can make your code behave more like synchronous with use of `async` and `await`:

```
view = async value => {
    let response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/addresses/show/'+ value, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + Auth.getToken(),
        },
        body: JSON.stringify()
    })
    let response = response.json();

    this.setState(
      { addressOject: responseData.data[0]},
      () =>  console.log(this.state.addressOject)
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fetch is asynchronous. That means it takes some time to complete but your rest of the code gets executed at that time.

Your `this.state.addressObject` is emptly at first. When you console it you get initial state, at that time fetch has not actually fetched the data so its giving same result.

If you are confirmed that your fetch will return some data then you can check it like this.

```
if(this.state.addressObject.length > 0) // do your stuff now
```

or if your fetch might return empty arry then you must declare state for fetching

```
this.state = {
    addressObject: [],
    fetched: false,
}
```

Now while fetching do this,

```
view = value => {
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/addresses/show/'+ value, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + Auth.getToken(),
        },
        body: JSON.stringify()
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseData) => {
        this.setState({ addressOject: responseData.data[0], fetched: true});

    })        

    console.log(this.state.addressOject)
}
```

Then you can check for the data only after fetched has given you the data.

```
if(this.state.fetched) // look for your data here
```

Hope it helps :)